# Multiple cron expression in cloudwatch event schedule

Tags: cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to schedule cloud watch event schedule  on a conditional way.

I want the CloudWatch to run every minute between 6.00AM Till 8.30PM Monday-Friday and rest all time it should run every 30minutes.

The Simple thing in my mind that I should use 2 event schedules one for every minutes from 6-8 and another for 30m for rest. Something  like bellow-

**EDT**

```
 1. * 6-19 * * 1-5
 2. 0-30/1 20 * * 1-5 
 3. */30 0-5,21-23 * * 1-5
```

**UTC**

```
1. * 11-1 * * 1-5
2. 0-30/1 2 * * 1-5 
3. */30 5-10,3-4 * * 1-5
```

**But my question is, is it possible  to combine all of the expression in one but do all of the scheduler?** or I need to use all 3 different commands?

I saw the cron and rate expression  here but couldn't find anything  like that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html